# Writing powershell commands directly in C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

I have the following code:

```
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

        // Call the PowerShell.AddCommand(string) method, add 
        // the Get-Process cmdlet to the pipeline. Do 
        // not include spaces before or after the cmdlet name 
        // because that will cause the command to fail.
        ps.AddCommand("mkdir");
        ps.AddArgument("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\test");
```

Unfortunately, when I run this piece of code, no directories are created. I guess I am misunderstanding how this works, but ideally, I want my final application to be able to run powershell commands and then grab the output directly within my application.

What am I doing wrong to execute a simple powershell command from my code?

Comment: add `ps.Invoke()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `ps.Invoke()` command for your powershell command. Just add it after command is build. Here is [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx) article about how to execute powershell commands.

Comment: Perfect. Say I have a script that I have execute, ie (python test.py) and in the test file I print "hello world". How can I read the output from executing that script?

Comment: @ryan look at the article there is example which execute powershell and get back result printing it to console